# Hironaka's construction for compact Kähler manifolds

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, birational-geometry, kahler-manifolds

In Hartshorne's book 《Algebraic Geometry》 p.443, the author introduces a construction of a non-projective complex manifold from a projective one. His method can be summarized as following:
Let $X$ be a projective complex threefold, take two non-singular curves $c,d\subseteq X$ which meet transversally at two points $P,Q$, and nowhere else. On $X-Q$, he first blow up the curve $c$, then blow up the strict transform of the curve $d$, we denote the result of these two blow-ups by $X_1$, on $X-P$, first blow up the curve $d$, then blow up the strict transform of the curve $c$, we denote the result of these two blow-ups on $X-P$ by $X_2$. On $X-P-Q$ it doesn't matter in which order we blow up the curves $c$ and $d$, so we can glue $X_1$ and $X_2$ along the inverse images of $X-P-Q$. The result is a non-projective compact complex manifold $\tilde X$.

My question is: where the is condition **projective** used? what if we change the condition projective manifold to any **compact Kähler** manifold (or maybe any compact complex manifold), do we still have these blow-up operations? is the result a manifold in Fujiki class $\mathcal C$? I guess the main point is to guarantee there exist two non-singular curves meet transversally at two points, then what's the most loose condition to ensure it? Any comment is welcome!

Comment: If this construction is meant to be a proof of the existence of non-projective compact Kähler manifolds, one has to start with something that is known to exists, i.e. a projective threefold. You can also define the blow-up of a complex manifold along a submanifold, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blowing_up#Blowing_up_submanifolds_in_complex_manifolds). Since blowing-up is a biholomorphic operation, if you start with something in $\mathcal C$, the result  would be in $\mathcal C$ as well?

Comment: Also to show that $\tilde X$ is not projective, one uses that $X$ is projective, but the morphism $\tilde X \to X$ is not projective.

Comment: Projectivity is used implicitly to find the curves; by embedding $X \subset \mathbb P^r$ and intersecting with a generic linearly embedded $\mathbb P^2 \subset \mathbb P^r$ we obtain (by Bertini's theorem) a nonsingular curve $c \subset X$. By choosing a second general plane in $\mathbb P^r$ which intersects the first in a sufficiently general line, we obtain $d$ (nonsingular by generality of the second plane) meeting $c$ transversely (by generality of the line) in some number of points. Now replace $X$ with its blowup along all but two points of $c\cap d$ and you have the needed setup.

Comment: So in other words, projectivity is not to ensure the existence of blowups but of curves.

Comment: @red_trumpet, so you mean for an arbitrary compact Kähler manifold, there may not exist such 2 curves meet at 2 points transversally, right?

Comment: There are even compact Kahler manifolds having no subvarieties

Comment: @NickL, ok, I think my question should be changed to: is there a non-projective compact Kähler manifold, such that we can find 2 non-singular curves meet at 2 points transversally, do you have any example?

Comment: @TabesBridges, thanks, from your comment, I know we can always find a projective manifold such that there exist 2 curves meet transversally at 2 points, by the way , do you have any example of non-projective compact Kähler manifold, such that it has such 2 curves?

Comment: Yes, such a thing exists. Just take four curves $C_1, \dotsc, C_4$ in a projective $X$, apply the procedure with $C_1, C_2$ and then the strict transforms of $C_3, C_4$ will be curves on $\tilde X$, which is not projective. Just ensure that $C_1 \cap C_2 \cap C_3 \cap C_4 = \emptyset$, otherwise $C_3$ and $C_4$ might not intersect in $\tilde X$.

Comment: @red_trumpet, you mean $C_1$ meets $C_3,C_4$ transversally at 2 points respectively, so is $C_2$? and $C_1\cap C_2=\emptyset=C_3\cap C_4$? Then which 2 curve are $c,d$ in our question?